# Facebook SDK 3.0 upload picture to a facebook page (not in album)

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi everyone I am a noob at android development I am trying to implement a feature that will allow the user to post a message on a Facebook page with an option to upload a picture/image from there device SD-card.

I am using Facebook sdk 3.0

I have managed to make it work but not on the Facebook page wall, rather via the users profile timeline.

Thanks in advance.

****EDIT****

```
case REQUEST_PICK_IMAGE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                imageUri = intent.getData();

                AsyncFacebookRunner mAsyncFbRunner1 = new AsyncFacebookRunner(mFacebook);
                Log.d(TAG, imageUri.toString() + " " + imageUri.getPath());
                Bundle params = new Bundle();
                try {
                    in = new FileInputStream(getRealPathFromURI(imageUri));
                    buf = new BufferedInputStream(in);
                    byte[] bMapArray= new byte[buf.available()];
                    buf.read(bMapArray);
                    params.putByteArray("picture", bMapArray);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
                params.putString("caption", "sample post via gallery");
                mAsyncFbRunner1.request("PAGE_ID" + "/feed", params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
            }
            break;
```

Comment: I haven't used the android sdk but if it's working posting to the user's timeline then I think all you need to do is change it from the user's id to the page's id. That's the way it works with PHP and JS SDK's but if you post the relevant code someone should be able to help.

Comment: Can you paste the api which you are using to upload a picture to the album

Comment: hi Rahul Patil see my EDITED post above i have included my code for uploading pic to facebook.

Comment: AsyncFacebookRunner is [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/AsyncFacebookRunner/) in SDK version 3.0. You should use Session. There are samples provided in the SDK for the same.

Comment: Also check this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/) under 'photos', it says the options it needs to create a post with photo.

Comment: hi @AshwiniBhangi your link was very helpful, can you give an example code maybe? i would really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Following code works for me. I am using latest Facebook SDK 3.0

```
showLoader(getResources().getString(R.string.sharing_on_facebook_wall));

Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() 
{
    public void onCompleted(com.facebook.Response response) 
    {
        hideLoader();

        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
        if (error != null) 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        else 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Posted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
Bundle postParams = new Bundle();

postParams.putString("name", "Title");
postParams.putString("link", "http://www.stackoverflow.com");
postParams.putString("description", "description");
postParams.putString("caption", "PictureTestApp");
postParams.putString("picture", imageUrl);

Request request = new Request(session, "me/feed", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```

Comment: hi @Shanthosh thanks for your answer but it the not what i am looking for. what you're trying to do with your code is posting to the user timeline with picture/image coming from a URL. i already know how to do that. what i want to do is posting a message to a facebook page with a picture/image from the phone's memory or SD-CARD.

Answer (score 0):

> "what i want to do is posting a message to a facebook page with a
>   picture/image from the phone's memory or SD-CARD."

At present there is no way to do this. The only place you can upload photos to from the SDCARD (rather than via a URL) is to a specific photo album.

Comment: That's not true. You can first get a list of all albums of the user and have to find the one with type == "wall" and post your image to that album.

Comment: so you're saying it *is true, but that there's a work around where you can post to an album called "wall" which behaves like the user's actual wall? If you're right (I have never heard of this workaround before) you should post that as the answer, since that sounds like exactly what the OP is looking for... Subsequently, I'd love to learn how to do this as well.

Comment: It's not called "wall", it has the type "wall" and it is the "album" containing all the images on the user's wall. I use it in my app Runbot which allows you to share your track-data along with an image of the map with the route on it.

Comment: ah, well then that's not what the OP wants, because simply sticking photos into the user's wall album doesn't produce the desired result in the user's stream.

Comment: yeah, well I hate that stupid Facebook API anyways. If their Android App would work like it should and correctly handle the SEND intent there would be no need for all this stuff. For e.g. Google+, you simply create the SEND intent, add text and image and you're done.

Comment: don't get me wrong... I 100% agree with you... that's why I was momentarily excited that maybe I missed something in all of my struggles with this piece of cr*p.